# How to limit entries in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: php, expressionengine

How to make a counter in ExpressionEngine?

{exp:weblog:entries weblog="news" limit="15"}

#### {title}

{body}

Posted on {entry_date format="%M %d, %Y - %h:%i %A"}

{/exp:weblog:entries}

it seems 'limit' limits the SQL Calls , but not actual results.... 
Should i add php?
more here: http://expressionengine.com/docs/modules/weblog/weblog_entries.html

Comment: I don't understand the question... limiting entries doesn't seem to have anything to do with making a counter.  could you maybe provide something that shows the output you expect?

Comment: I'm as confused as Ty, but want to note that the weblog tag has a built-in counter: http://expressionengine.com/docs/modules/weblog/variables.html#var_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="news" limit="15"}
**{count}**
{title}
{body}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
{exp:stats weblog="news"}
 {total_entries}
{/exp:stats}
```

As others mentioned, not entirely sure what you mean by counter vs. 'limit entries'. Limit entries will simply pull that number or entries per page (SQL may actually pull more for pagination).

Count is a built in single variable for the exp:weblog:entries tag. If you want the total count of entries in that weblog you could pull the number of total entries using the [statistics module](http://expressionengine.com/docs/modules/statistics/index.html).